# C++ whats wrong with that code fstream

Tags: c++

need some help with C++ code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
using namespace std;


    class open_file
    {

        string list_cont;
        fstream newlist;
        newlist.open("lista.txt",ios::in);
        while (newlist.good())
        {
            getline(newlist, list_cont);
            cout << list_cont << endl;
        }
        newlist.close();

    };
```

Visual Studio keeps getting me  Error   102 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

Duno why, Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put your code in a method. That's not valid C++

Comment: Asker lacks basic understanding of the language.

Comment: @Columbo obviously...that's why he's here.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu ... and it's also why he is wrong here (This site is completely wrong for teaching C++ fundamentals). The above comment is part of a close-vote btw., so just ignore it.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı: method? you *do* mean "member function" right?

Comment: @frasnian yes I do, although method is a pretty common term to refer to member functions.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı: I know.  But in C++, we generally say "member function" - methods are for Java.  I just didn't put the little smiley-face emoticon at the end of my comment.

Comment: @frasnian Here you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `class open_file` with `void open_file()` and remove the last semicolon. Your problem is you're trying to declare a function but you used the class keyword instead.

Comment: Thank you very much !
It's working now.
Sorry about stupid question, but i've just started learning C++